# How to get the unaligned data of multiple measurement points in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I checked the official guide of Apache IoTDB, and it seems like most of the examples are based on the time series are aligned. I wonder if the time series are not aligned, is there a way to query out the data values of multiple measurement points?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please